# why I always having errors with this appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

[I was doing this and been updating this few times but still having errors like
Error
Script function not found: createCalendarEvent
Error
Exception: Invalid argument: [Ljava.lang.Object;@4432521f]

What should I do? I have spreadsheet where I pull the information. I want this to create a calendar event which is automatic when I add something or edit the spreadsheet.

link of photo here :  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7nAy.png)

Comment: Please provide your script as the text in your question. And, where does the error of `Exception: Invalid argument: [Ljava.lang.Object;@4432521f]` occur in your script?

Comment: The name of your function is `createCalendarEvents` not `createCalendarEvent`

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, can you please click the link of the photo.  sorry, I really can't put the script here because I don't understand how to format it. sorry. I am really not into this kind of work but I have to. In the photo shows the exact script that I am using. And it always have error saying invalid argument in this part                                                                   
      var event = calendar.createEvents(eventName, eventDate, eventEndTime, {
      description: "Please join the meeting for discussion.",
      guests: [guest1Email, guest2Email]
    });

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From the official document of `createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)`, `guests` of `options` is `String, a comma-separated list of email addresses that should be added as guests`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options) So, please modify `guests` to `guests: [guest1Email, guest2Email].join(",")` and test it again. And, in this case, I found [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64350698). So I flagged it.